# Can I use an old MySQL database 4.1 data in a 5.0 server?

Tags: mysql

I'm not an advanced database user, so now I would move an old site to a new hosting where I have all new material, can I use an old MySQL `database 4.1 data` **in** a `5.0.51a server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem there. Just export your database from MySQL 4:

```
mysqldump -p --opt dbname >dbname.sql
```

and import it in your MySQL 5:

```
mysql -p -D dbname <dbname.sql
```

Just a note: In MySQL version 5, the field type `varchar binary` is no longer available.

Comment: there is an `/usr/bin/mysql_upgrade` which handles a bunch of the schema conversions